# System outage when only one of two HAProxy servers is down. Failover doesn't seem to be working

Tags: haproxy, high-availability, failover, keepalived

First of all my experience with HAProxy stack is just one day old so I hope my question makes sense.

I have 2 HAProxy VMs and 2 Apache VMs (vagrant machines) as follows.

```
192.168.50.11 HAPROXY VM1
192.168.50.12 HAPROXY VM2
192.168.50.21 APACHE VM1
192.168.50.22 APACHE VM2

192.168.50.10 FLOATING IP - set in keepalived of both HAProxy servers above
```

If I bring one of the Apache servers down and call `http://192.168.50.10` system still works which is fine. However, if I bring one of the HAProxy servers down, whole service is down. Based on my configurations below, could you please tell me what I'm missing here?

**HAPROXY SETTINGS ON BOTH SERVERS**

**/etc/default/haproxy**

```
ENABLED=1
```

**/etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg**

```
global
    log /dev/log local0
    log 127.0.0.1 local1 notice
    user haproxy
    group haproxy
    maxconn 2000
    daemon

defaults
    log global
    mode http
    option httplog
    option dontlognull
    retries 3
    option redispatch
    timeout connect 5000
    timeout client 50000
    timeout server 50000

listen webservers 192.168.50.10:80
    balance roundrobin
    stats enable
    stats auth admin:admin
    stats uri /haproxy?stats
    option httpchk
    option forwardfor
    option http-server-close
    server webserver1 192.168.50.21:80 check
    server webserver2 192.168.50.22:80 check
```

**KEEPALIVED SETTINGS ON BOTH SERVERS**

**/etc/sysctl.conf**

```
net.ipv4.ip_nonlocal_bind=1
```

**etc/keepalived/keepalived.conf**

```
vrrp_script chk_haproxy {
    script "killall -0 haproxy"
    #Ping every 2 seconds
    interval 2
    weight 2
}

vrrp_instance VI_1 {
    interface eth0
    state MASTER
    virtual_router_id 51
    priority 11
    virtual_ipaddress {
        192.168.50.10
    }
    track_script {
        chk_haproxy
    }
}
```

**Note:** Only `priority` is VM dependent so it is `priority 11` for `192.168.50.11 HAPROXY VM1` machine and `priority 12` for `192.168.50.12 HAPROXY VM2` machine.

I created this example after reading the blog posts below.

- [Setting Up A High-Availability Load Balancer (With Failover And
  Session Support) With HAProxy/Keepalived On Debian Lenny](https://www.howtoforge.com/setting-up-a-high-availability-load-balancer-with-haproxy-keepalived-on-debian-lenny)
- [HOW TO SETUP HAPROXY WITH KEEPALIVED](http://dasunhegoda.com/how-to-setup-haproxy-with-keepalived/833/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I thought, small mistakes were in place for keepalived config file.

`state MASTER` for 192.168.50.11 `# This is the master HAProxy`

`state BACKUP` for 192.168.50.12 `# This is the failover HAProxy`

And

`priority 12` for 192.168.50.11 `# the higher priority goes with the master HAProxy`

`priority 11` for 192.168.50.12

Comment: There are a few good examples here for learners. http://www.inanzzz.com/index.php/posts/haproxy